# Get A specific Data from a url

Tags: php

I looked up the other answers but none of them seem to work right for me because those who answered forgot to add comment. Am trying to get a specific P tage from div in a url. i have 3 case but how can i get the first `<p>` in `div class="entry-content"` in any of the cases.

CASE 1

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <p> want to get content here </p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <div></div>
  </div>
```

CASE 2

```
  <div class="entry-content">
    <div></div>
    <p> want to get content here </p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <div></div>
   </div>
```

CASE 3

```
  <div class="entry-content">
    <p> want to get content here </p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

.PHP

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.myurl.com/');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$p=$doc->getElementByClassName('entry-content')->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0);
echo $p->nodeValue;
```

Comment: You are not looking for the first element inside the `entry-content` element as you coded, but the first `<p>` element inside.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PHP's DOMXPath class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to select elements with a class. [PHP's DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) does not have `getElementsByClassName` method.

```
<?php
    $html = file_get_contents('http://www.myurl.com/');

    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $finder = new DomXPath($doc);
    $p = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'entry-content')]")->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0);

    echo $p->nodeValue;
?>
```

Comment: this the message "Call to undefined method DOMDocument::query()"

Comment: That's weird, I don't get the same error as you do. I get a lot of errors just with this code: http://pastebin.com/Z5gmLK4N because the page's HTML is not valid HTML. It has several elements with the same ID which are throwing it off from the start. Hmm, I'll see if I can find how to bypass that...

Answer (score 0):

With jquery it is easy:

```
var firstP = $('.entry-content p:first');
```

But your code looks like php, so I am a little confused what do you want to archive.

Comment: how can i add it to php?